# "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" error found on importing file in the same directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As17G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlG2x.png)

cannot import Users array from users.js file

Tried importing with import statement as well as with

```js
const Users = require('users')' // this is the code i have been using to import the file
```

Both files , index.js and users.js are in same directory

Comment: You need a relative path... `./users`

Comment: I also tried with import {Users} from './users' , it didnt work

Comment: with `import` you'd possibly need `./users.js`

Comment: Try not to mix ES imports with CJS `require()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using modules then you must change the export type to `module.exports= {Users}` or `export.Users = Users`.

Import the users in the `index.js` file as

```js
const { Users } = require("./users.js");
```

Check the CodeSandbox to resolve your problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/modest-frog-g6rtkr?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrle0006356hh0oe4dih%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0002356hsa36j1ep%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0004356het29m2l8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0005356hlb99lf6z%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr75vrld0002356hsa36j1ep%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0001356hpp6zpaad%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0002356hsa36j1ep%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0001356hpp6zpaad%2522%257D%252C%2522clr75vrld0005356hlb99lf6z%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0005356hlb99lf6z%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr75yvyd009o356hhyj85ccw%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75yvyd009o356hhyj85ccw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clr75vrld0004356het29m2l8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0004356het29m2l8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0003356h6tq0s0f5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr75vrld0003356h6tq0s0f5%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).